# Why does this function only return one object when two are initialized?

Tags: javascript

I have initialized two objects, yet when I resize (which triggers a function that writes each object name) it only writes the *last* object.

I just switched from jQuery to writing vanilla Javascript so if the code doesn't make sense, is missing something or is just plain wrong, please let me know! I more than welcome criticism, I just want to learn the right way.

Anyway, any help figuring out why it only returns the second/last object? 
**CodePen**
https://codepen.io/kmarmet/pen/NYQvWV?editors=1011

**Code**

```
const Obj = function(options) {
    const cont = document.querySelector('.cont');
    const obj = options.objClass;
    let delay = function() {};
    const whenDone = () => cont.innerHTML += `${obj}<br>`;

    return window.onresize = () => {
        clearTimeout(delay);
        return delay = setTimeout(whenDone, 100);
    };
};

const one = new Obj({
    sliderClass: 'slider-1'
});

const two = new Obj({
    objClass: 'slider-2'
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're overwriting the `window.onresize` property…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only assign one event handler via `window.onresize`. Use `addEventListener` instead:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        clearTimeout(delay);
        delay = setTimeout(whenDone, 100);
});
```

Moreover, it doesn’t make much sense to return something from a constructor, nor does returning from a `resize` event listener.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually wrote it in CoffeeScript and it didn't have those returns. I converted it via https://decaffeinate-project.org and didn't realize it had the returns in it...In any case, thank you for the reply and the answer.